# How do I add values in Excel when there is information besides the desired values that are present?

Tags: excel

Here's my problem:

I download data from a database and it automatically pulls the date that the data was entered.  My cells look like the following:

```
7/21/12: 3
7/22/12: 3
```

I need to be able to add the numbers in Excel, but the dates in the cell prevent me from doing so.  I need to either find a way to delete the dates from the cells, or find a way to add the digits despite the dates being present in the cell.  We have tried splitting the cells but because there are more than one value in each cell it hasn't been possible

Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, I would want the result to be 6.  Double digits would be the maximum value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what OP asked (ie cells like so `7/21/12: 3 7/22/12: 3`) a formula solution might be:

```
=MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1),FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)-FIND(" ",A1))+RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)+1))
```

If a different question then a different answer. However as suggested by @durbnpoisn Text to Columns may be more practical.

The formula is in two parts:

```
MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1),FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)-FIND(" ",A1))
```

to find the first value of interest (`3` associated with 7/21/12) which is then added (`+`) to:

```
RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)+1))
```

which finds the other `3` (the one associated with 7/22/12).

Both use string functions. One to pick out characters in the middle ([MID](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/mid.php)) and one at the end ([RIGHT](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/right.php)). Because we can't count characters right to left we subtract from the total number instead with [LEN](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/len.php).

[FIND](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/find.php) hogs the limelight because it is searching for a space `" "` when each of the first, second and third instances (so we know where we are in the cell given that the date format may have one or two digits for month and that the relevant values may be one or two digits). Having found the first space we know if we start one cell further in with what would otherwise be the same search as for the first occurrence we will get the second occurrence - and again for the final occurrence of interest.

Comment: Your formula works perfect when there are two values in the cell but I can't figure out how to get it to work if there are three or four values in the cell.  I also am still looking to add the values of multiple different cells together (inter addition versus intra addition)

Comment: Thanks for your help pnuts...I changed  the title to try to better reflect my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the cells at the : delimeter, which would give you two columns, date and number.
Go to the Data tab, and click "text to columns".  Choose your delimeter.

Or, you can run your math based on the Right(cell,1) character (assuming it's one digit).

```
=SUM(RIGHT(F13,1),RIGHT(F14,1))
```

You're probably best with the split.

Comment: Great start, the problem is that using your formula it is only taking one of the values from the cell.  For example Cell 1: 4/2/12: 3 4/4/12:4 and then Cell 2 4/3/12: 7 is giving me 11 not 14...the way the database exports results in having more than one value per cell

Comment: Well, I did say that there was an assumption with that formula.  And I also said, you were better off splitting the cell.  If this is live data you are talking about, you can write a macro to perform that split for you.

Comment: Splitting the cell doesn't work because the length of the dates can change making it impossible to tell it to split at the same place each time.

Comment: The split occurs at the delimeter, so the length is not an issue.  You may have to split it twice - at the space, then at the colon.  If you can't rely on your data always being the same, you really have a problem with your data that you have to solve first.  You should never have more than one value in your data cell.

Comment: I completely agree with you but unfortunately that is how the database works.

Comment: Can you modify the data to add an additional delimeter to seperate the individual records in each column?

Comment: Unfortunately, not.  I'm sorry if I'm asking a question that cannot be solved

Comment: It's not that it can't be solved exactly.  But in order to write a reliable formula, you need consistency in the data.